# Use ConstraintLayout to manage fragment position

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, android-constraintlayout

I have a question, what I want to do is to use ConstraintLayout that i have (all of its properties, also) to add and position a fragment in execution time.

I'd like to do so using code and not through xml.

By now, the following code works, but the only thing it does is to put the fragment through SupportFragmentManager but I don't know how to modify its position using the ConstraintLayout, because theoretically, I could use it to position my fragment to the bottom (currently, it goes to top).

My Activity onCreate is the following (it works, but not the way i want).

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //TODO use constraintLayout to manage fragment position (ask)
    ConstraintLayout activityLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_app_container);
    if (activityLayout != null){
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }

        TabFragment tabFragment = TabFragment.newInstance();
        tabFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.main_app_container, tabFragment)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

My ConstraintLayout xml (main_activity.xml) is the following if needed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_app_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.xdxdxdxd.android.xdxdxdxd.MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

you can see Below picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The way to use constraints:

```
    ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();

    set.clone(activityLayout);

    set.connect(ViewObject1, StartSide, ViewObject2, EndSide, Margin)

    set.applyTo(activityLayout);
```

There are a bunch of global constants for the start, end and object values, you should check out the [documents here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet.html).